# how to run query inside a custom validator in phalconphp

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

Im trying to make a custom validator to check if an email is already submited or not. for this I need to execute query in my custom validator, How can I do that?

```
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator,

Phalcon\Validation\ValidatorInterface,

Phalcon\Validation\Message;

Class Unique extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface {

    public function validate($validator, $attribute)   {
       // how to execute "SELECT * FROM myTable" here...     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myTable` is mapped to a Model you can just:

```
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator;
use Phalcon\Validation\ValidatorInterface;
use Phalcon\Validation\Message;
use MyTable;

class Unique extends Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate($validator, $attribute)
    {
        $result = MyTable::findFirst("id = 1 AND status = 'sent'");
        ...
    }
}
```